# I am working on login button and there is an error on if statement. Don't know how to solve it

Tags: android-studio

```
         BtnReg = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
       Button btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        etUsername =findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPass = findViewById(R.id.etPass);
    
        dataBase = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDataBase.class, "user-database.db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        UserDao db = dataBase.userDao();


        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = etPass.getText().toString();
               User user=  userDao.getUser(username,password);
```

> ```
>  Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.example.worksheet3.Data.User
> ```
>
> com.example.worksheet3.Data.UserDao.getUser(java.lang.String,
> java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

```
                if ( user !=null) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unregistered user, or incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a method() to search for the user(username and password) in your database helper. Then you can come back and call your database helper method in your if statement to login. If you don't know how to code the needed method please Shout